# sql query confusion with count

Tags: mysql, postgresql

im trying to fgure out this query from a sql book im reading.

6. Find the name of the most popular course based on the number of the times the course was offered.

i have the query up to were it lists the courses and counts how many times each has been offered, now my question is how do satisfy the question above lol. how can i get just the course that was offered the most ? (ie. the databases course)

my query is

```
SELECT
    count(s.course_id) AS Times_Offered,
    c.title
FROM
    sections s
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY    c.title
ORDER BY    Times_Offered DESC;
```

my query shows up as

```
times_offered   title
     3        Databases
     3        Calculus 1
     2        Compilers
     2        Elocution
     2        Acting
     1        Topology
```

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to your query?

Comment: lol i think i figured it out , is it alright to use limit 1 to achieve this?

Comment: @Paul lol you answered at the same time as me. thats exactly wha ti was thinking but i didnt know if that was ok to do. but it works. thanks!

Comment: Depends. "Calculus 1" also has been offered three times, so it would be as valid as "Databases".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count them and then show the one with the highest number only, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.course_id) 
AS Times_Offered, c.title FROM sections s 
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id=s.course_id 
GROUP BY c.title 
ORDER BY Times_Offered DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ty , that took care of my problem. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As you want the most popular course you need to get all the max offered courses. which will give your expected answer.

```
SELECT 
count(s.course_id) AS Times_Offered,
c.title
FROM
sections s
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY    c.title
ORDER BY    Times_Offered DESC
Having Times_Offered =
SELECT max(t1.Times_offered) from
(SELECT 
count(s.course_id) AS Times_Offered,
c.title
FROM
sections s
INNER JOIN courses c ON c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY    c.title
ORDER BY    Times_Offered DESC) t1
```

Your Answer should be

```
times_offered   title
 3        Databases
 3        Calculus 1
```